# i have a samsung galaxy s6 edge dont have google password

Tags: password-protection

i have the galaxy S6 Edge don't  know google account password is there anything i can do to use the phone the phone says there was an unauthorized factory reset i purchased the phone second hand and can no longer find the person i purchased the phone from

Answer (score 0):

You need to flash new ROM using Odin. ***Before*** you do it, wipe the /system and /data partition. If this don't helps, you probably need to take your phone to service.